Solving the high school algebra problem
We learned many identities involving addition, multiplication and exponentiation in highschool, for example:
$$ \begin{aligned}
(a+b)c &= ac + bc \\
(a b)^c &= a^c b^c \\
(a^b)^c &= a^{bc}
\end{aligned} $$
etc. Can you write a program that, given an equation involving these operations, determine whether it is a valid identity? To avoid problems like \$0^0 = 1\$, we only consider positive integers, and there're no subtraction or division.
This is code-golf, and standard loopholes apply.
Input
The input is two expressions made out of positive integers, variables, addition, multiplication and exponentiation.
You are free to use any reasonable input format that's convenient, as this challenge isn't about parsing. For example, you can use a string with infix notation, or reverse polish notation. Directly inputting syntax trees is also allowed. You can represent variables and numbers in any format, as long as there are sufficiently many distinct variables, and you can assume nothing exceeds the native integer type range (but see this loophole). Since addition and multiplication is associative and commutative, you can also require consecutive additions be represented as a list or a multiset, etc.
Output
If the two expressions are equal no matter what positive integers the variables are set to, output a truthy value. Otherwise output a falsey value.
Examples
A list of identities taught in school:
a + b = b + a
(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)
a * b = b * a
(a * b) * c = a * (b * c)
a * 1 = a
(a + b) * c = a * c + b * c
1^a = 1
a^1 = a
a^(b * c) = (a^b)^c
a^(b + c) = a^b * a^c
(a * b)^c = a^c * b^c

(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2 * a * b + b^2

Some random non-identities
1 + 1 != 3
a + b != a
a^(b^c) != (a^b)^c
a + (b * c) != (a + b) * (a + c)
(a + b)^c != a^c + b^c

Wilkie's identity, or the tricky identity that ruins your solution:
$$(A^y + B^y)^x (C^x + D^x)^y = (A^x + B^x)^y (C^y + D^y)^x$$
where \$A,B,C,D\$ are any expressions satisfying \$AD = BC\$, for example \$A = 1 + x\$, \$B = 1 + x + x^2\$, \$C = 1 + x^3\$, \$D = 1 + x^2 + x^4\$.

The following is one possible solution to the problem. Stop reading if you want to figure this out yourself.
Let's take the one-variable case first. Consider the difference of the two sides. Suppose we know its derivative is either always zero or has at most \$n\$ zeros, then the difference itself is either always zero or has at most \$(n+1)\$ zeros. So we can repeatedly take derivatives until the expression becomes a constant (which is either always zero or has at most 0 zeros), and then we just have to sample the expression at \$k\$ different points for a fixed \$k\$, if they are all zero, then the expression is always zero.
However, taking derivatives doesn't always simplify the expression. For example the derivative of \$x^x\$ is \$x^x (1 + \ln x)\$. However, as we are only interested in the number of zeros, we can remove the first factor and investigate \$(1 + \ln x)\$ instead, which is simpler. We can try to make this more rigorous:
Let's call a valid expression in the challenge a positive expression, and from now on allow a general expression to contain subtraction and natural logarithm (however, arguments of exponentiations and logarithms must still be positive expressions). We can define a metric of complexity, where a sum, difference or product is as complex as the most complicated summand/factor/etc., the complexity of \$\ln A\$ is one plus the complexity of \$A\$, and the complexity of \$A^B\$ is \$1 + \max\{\textrm{comp}(B), 1 + \textrm{comp}(A)\}\$. Then the derivative is obviously at most as complex as the original function. Moreover, we can guarantee that for any expression \$f\$, we have \$a f' = b f + c\$, where \$a,b,c\$ are simpler expressions, by recursion.
But wait, we expected \$a f' = b f\$. So how does having an extra \$+c\$ term help? Well, integration magic:
$$f = \exp\left(\int \frac{b(x)}{a(x)} \textrm dx\right) \left(\textrm{const} + \int \frac{c(x)}{a(x)} \exp \left(-\int \frac{b(x)}{a(x)} \textrm dx\right) \textrm dx\right).$$
If \$c\$ is either always zero or has at most \$k\$ zeros, then \$f\$ is either always zero or has at most \$(k+1)\$ zeros (think about why this is true), which is exactly what we need for our idea to work.
We can also solve the multi-variable case recursively. Suppose we already know how to solve the \$n\$-variable case. Then we can apply the procedure described above, but we take partial derivatives wrt \$x_{n+1}\$, instead of derivatives. This will recursively call the decision procedure for the \$n\$-variable case, which solves the problem.
I can post a non-competing Haskell submission if more detail is needed. You can also read the original paper where this problem is solved.

Is it a solution to try some small values? Any example that equal for small values but not when large?

@l4m2 As long as you can prove that the number of small values you tried is sufficient, it is a solution. (The solution I sketched does exactly that.) However, there are examples that are equal for arbitrarily many small values, by Lagrange interpolation.

To first not equal for variables =n, is it always necessary more than n tokens? Linear seems easiest implemented

@l4m2 These type of questions are known as witness conjectures. I don't know whether your particular statement is known or not, but good luck finding the answer.
